# how to determine (QTY) monthly new customer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using the following selecting code to determine monthly new customers.

Step 1:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by so.ClientID desc) as ID, *
into #t1
    from(
        select  so.ClientID, so.Product, so.StatementID, CONCAT(ClientID, CustomerGroup, Product) AS Code
        from    RG_SalesOut_Report so inner join Reporting.dbo.BrandNameForNCR br
                on br.BrandName=so.Brand
            where   so.Block=0 AND so.[All Sources]='SalesOUT' AND so.Value_CP>0 AND so.Amount>0
            group by    so.ClientID, so.Product, so.StatementID, CONCAT(ClientID, CustomerGroup, Product)
                        ) so
            order by    so.ClientID desc, so.Product, so.StatementID desc
```

Spet 2:

```
select  distinct tab1.ClientID as NewClientID, tab1.StatementID as MonthSales
    from #t1 tab1
    RIGHT JOIN #t1 tab2
    on tab1.ID=tab2.ID-1
    where IIF(tab1.code=tab2.code, DATEDIFF(MONTH,tab2.StatementID, tab1.StatementID), 0)=0
```

I got the following results:

[image]

I want to get the followoing results:

[image]

From this table we can see that in **Jan-10** we have got ***5 new customers*** and in **Feb-10** - ***1 new customer*** and so on

How to determine quantity of monthly new customers?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what the output of Sum(so.Amount) AS Amount column? what is the use of this . What is the logic of Qty-monthly calculation?

Comment: Ajay2707, thanks. output of Sum(so.Amount) as Amount is nothing, it's my mistake, sorry. I removed the extra columns. I hope that now you are understanding. Thanks again

Comment: But question still is (QTY) monthly new customer? what is the logic or qty column of new customer? Your temp table does store qty of each customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the desired results in 2 steps:

1. Store the results of your step 2 in another temp table, say #tmp2. I would, however, prefer to use a Common Table Expression (CTE) for steps 1 and 2 instead of creating temp tables.

   **Note:** CTE is better in case the result set is small, but temp tables are better for large result sets.
2. Group by customer and select the minimum date corresponding to each customer, then order by the date, like so:

   ```
   select newclientid, min(monthsales) as 'monthsales'
   from #tmp2
   group by newclientid
   order by monthsales
   ```